# Get Emails from Multiple Inboxes using EWS Managed API 2.2

Tags: exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

Is it possible to retrieve emails from multiple inboxes using EWS Managed API 2.2?  I am able to retrieve email from an Inbox using ExchangeService passing in Credentials to the service call then doing a FindItems on the service connection.  All of this works good.

I would like to get emails from multiple inboxes using a single call.  Is this possible.  Any sample code would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acces EWS through either [Oauth, NTLM or Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn626019(v=exchg.150).aspx)-authentication, which all are per-request authentication schemes. Oauth takes some initial setup, and NTLM takes 3 requests in total for every EWS request, but in either way, it's just for one user at a time.